# add a div overlay on fullscreen video on mobile browser and ie11

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to add something overlay on fullscreen

as this demo (i found this on internet, not my code)

```
print ('http://jsfiddle.net/carmijoon/pZbkX/')
```

It works on desktop chrome, safari but did not work on ie11 and mobile chrome, safari. And browser compatibility of the demo above is the same.

Somebody know how to hack to achieve this goal?

Comment: Do you mean its not responsive when you say its doesnt work on mobile?

Comment: I mean that what i expect should overlay on fullscreen did not overlay, just fullscreen video.